# Resize Row Heights Depending on Background Image Details in Zurb's Foundation

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, background-image

This is a hard one to explain, so I'll do my best.

As it stands now, I have a wrapper div that has the iceberg image as it's background. It's styled in that the background image sizes to fit the user's screen. Within that wrapper div, I have two .rows, each containing a column.

Now the tricky part: I want one row to just span the top of the water, with the other spanning the bottom of the water. [Here's a rough concept.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsTsL.png)

Right now these rows are given a min-height to match that horizon, however when the user resizes their screen or has a different browser width than my dev environment, of course it doesn't work the same.

Now, how can I go about getting these rows to match heights with the background image? I had considered slicing the image into two, but I imagine there's got to be a much more resourceful way. Here's the CodePen I'm working with: http://codepen.io/jwindeknecht/pen/qOqwPp

If you can offer any advice or if I can clear anything up, let me know! Thanks.

---

```
<div class="hero">
  <div class="row over">
    <div class="large-6 large-offset-6 columns">
      <div class="inside">
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row under">
    <div class="large-6 large-offset-6 columns">
      <div class="inside">
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

```
.hero {
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/fdRuNIF.jpg) center top no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  min-width: 100%;

  div {
    display: table;

    .inside {
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }

  }

}

.over div { min-height: 275px; }
.under div { min-height: 275px; }
```

Comment: Instead of adding 15 links try adding your relevant code, if someone searches this answer in a couple months from now, these links probably will be no good and the question will no longer be useful.

Comment: Noted. Went ahead and added the code--thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: One more thing, now you can update your codepen with the actual link, and you will have a good question :)

Comment: Fair enough, link added. :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay! I figured this out. I know the dimensions of the image, so I had the *min-height* of the row set to a certain percentage of the the width of the image.

e.g. The image is 1500px wide. The row that covers just the horizon is 300px high. Therefor the *min-height* of the row is set to *20vw*.

So regardless of the background image width, the height of the row matches up due to using the *vw*. Here's a pen example: http://codepen.io/jwindeknecht/pen/RWyBGW

And the new code is simple:

```
.over div { min-height: 275px; }
```

to

```
.over div { min-height: 20vh; }
```